# Merging two datasets with unequal dates in R

Tags: r, date, merge

DF1: Has dates between 2021-04-20 and 2022-05-15 for each group. In other words, group 1001 starts at 2021-04-20 and ends at 2022-05-15. The same is true for group 1002.

| Date | Group |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-04-20 | 1001 |
| 2021-04-21 | 1001 |
| 2021-04-22 | 1001 |
| 2021-04-23 | 1001 |
| 2021-04-24 | 1001 |
| 2021-04-25 | 1001 |
| 2021-04-26 | 1001 |
| ... | ... |
| 2022-04-12 | 1001 |
| 2022-04-13 | 1001 |
| 2022-04-14 | 1001 |
| 2022-05-15 | 1001 |
| 2021-04-20 | 1002 |
| 2021-04-21 | 1002 |
| 2021-04-22 | 1002 |
| 2021-04-23 | 1002 |
| 2021-04-24 | 1002 |
| 2021-04-25 | 1002 |
| 2021-04-26 | 1002 |
| ... | ... |
| 2022-04-12 | 1002 |
| 2022-04-13 | 1002 |
| 2022-04-14 | 1002 |
| 2022-05-15 | 1002 |

DF2: This dataset has random dates between 2021-04-20 and 2022-05-15 for each group. It has has count values for New and Processed.

| Date | Group | New | Processed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-04-20 | 1001 | 100 | 0 |
| 2021-04-27 | 1001 | 56 | 1 |
| 2021-04-29 | 1001 | 0 | 0 |
| 2021-05-03 | 1001 | 45 | 1 |
| 2021-05-05 | 1001 | 23 | 0 |
| 2021-07-20 | 1002 | 0 | 1 |
| 2021-07-26 | 1002 | 43 | 0 |
| 2021-07-30 | 1002 | 25 | 10 |
| 2021-09-01 | 1002 | 0 | 1 |
| 2021-09-19 | 1002 | 50 | 15 |
| 2021-09-23 | 1002 | 23 | 0 |

DFDesired: What I would like is to merge DF1 and DF2 so that groups 1001 and 1002 start at 2021-04-20 and end at 2022-05-15 and go day by day. I would also like the values for new and processed to be filled for the dates that they are currently filled in DF2. For example, on 2021-04-20 for group 1001, New should = 100 and Processed = 0. But for 2021-04-21 for 1001. both those values should be 0.

Comment: Could you please share your data using `dput`?

Comment: `library(tidyr);`
`DF1 %>% full_join(DF2, by = c("Date", "Group")) %>% mutate(across(where(is.numeric), ~ replace_na(.x, 0)))`

Comment: @Mohanasundaram if I wanted to merge more than 2 datasets with the same parameters as above, can I just do: `DF1 %>% full_join(DF2, DF3, by = c("Date", "Group")) %>% mutate(across(where(is.numeric), ~ replace_na(.x, 0)))`

Comment: `DF1 %>% full_join(DF2, by = c("Date", "Group")) %>% full_join(DF3, by = c("Date", "Group")) %>% mutate(across(where(is.numeric), ~ replace_na(.x, 0)))` would work.